# Make half screen with react native view and half with android native view

Tags: react-native

Is it possible to get the react native root view and to put it on the bottom half screen and put the android native view on top half of the screen?

If yes how?

Comment: You could try to wrap your android view in a custom react native module and use react-native to show it on half the screen

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-android.html